# List Date/Time column only shows times as "12:00"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, date-time

I have a list that has a date/time field, which is set to display date and time (not Date Only).  However, whenever times are captured in this field, the time always shows "12:00".  Is there something I'm missing in order to make this show the correct time?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default value if you don't select the time you need.

You could change the time as needed:

[image]

Or if you want to capture the current time, go to list settings> choose the date column> set the default value as now:

[image]

After this, when we add a new list item, the date and time column will show current time as default value:

[image]